# Erratic errors loading image with Texture2d.LoadImage(byte[]) on Android devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I have an app which has to create `Sprite`-instances on the fly based on data contained in byte arrays (PNGs and JPGs). The following code is used to create the sprites:

```
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2, TextureFormat.RGBA32,false,false); 
texture.LoadImage(data);
Vector2 pivot = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
Rect tRect = new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height);        
return Sprite.Create(texture, tRect, pivot);
```

This works fine, however, depending on the device and the size of the images, after a random number of images, the app freezes and then will be shut down by the OS. Its always another image, which fails. Also, the data source is irrelevant.

Looking into the logs of the app via adb shows nothing. If I write to the debug log, I can see, that the last statement which gets called is `texture.LoadImage`. However, there is no exception or another information about the error. Catching the exception does also not work.

The error does not occur in the editor. The error occurs on the android devices (2) in development build and in production build.

Searching the web, I found the below entry, which states the very same problem, but no solution has been posted (they circled around the www-part, however the problem is not with that):

https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-crash-when-using-multiple-www.483941/

**UPDATE**

One interesting finding is, that if I set the `markNonReadable`-Parameter of the  `texture.LoadImage()` method to true, the error occurs less frequently, but still is there.

```
texture.LoadImage(data,true);
```

Comment: How do you load images?

Comment: Normaly via a webservice, however I tried also from resource folder. with the same effect. In the end its a byte array (byte[]). The image-data is not corrupted.

Comment: Try to wait 0.1 - 0.5 seconds before loading the next image.

Comment: In normal operation, this is the case. There are always timespans of many seconds between each load operation. However, this makes no difference. After a random number of images, it fails.

Comment: Are you sure it's not because there's insufficient memory? How do you dispose of the previously created sprites and Texture2D's?

Comment: @Aleksandr: It was indeed just a memory problem. I wrongly ruled out that prematurely, because of the random occurrence of the error. I released the sprite only by clearing the references to it. However, this seems not enough. After calling DestroyImmediate on both the texture and the sprite, the problems vanished. Make your comment to an answer and I will accept it. Maybe you also may want to write into your answer, what the best way is, to release the sprite and its texture? Thanks, you saved me a lot of grief,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textures are not garbage collected. So if you create a texture using new Texture then you need to destroy the texture with Destroy(texture) when you no longer need it. I believe Sprite object also needs to be destroyed.
In your case, textures that were loaded stayed in memory until Android OS closed your app because of memory pressure.
UnloadUnusedAssets() should also destroy all the textures and sprites that are no longer referenced, but it takes a lot of time (about 1 second), so it only makes sense to call that when changing scenes.